# Task schedule in windows server from other computer

Tags: vb.net, scheduled-tasks, windows-server

I am scheduling a task from vb.net with these parameters. Generates the task correctly and executes it. This works correctly in local, but I need that task to be created on the server. Any ideas?

```
Using tService As New TaskService()
    Dim Fecha As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(txtFDesde.Text + " " + txtHDesde.Text)
    Dim tTime As New TimeTrigger()
    Dim tDefinition As TaskDefinition = tService.NewTask
    tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Tarea programada para ejecutar"
    tDefinition.Settings.RunOnlyIfLoggedOn = False
    tTime.StartBoundary = New DateTime(Fecha.Year, Fecha.Month, Fecha.Day, Fecha.Hour, Fecha.Minute, 0)
    tDefinition.Triggers.Add(tTime)
    Dim url As String = "http://localhost:5000/" & Param
    tDefinition.Actions.Add(New ExecAction("cmd.exe", "/c start " & url))
    tService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Test " & Param, tDefinition)
End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the static connect method...you'll need credentials to the server....https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383451(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I use the example and it's working! It is possible to run whether user is logged on or not??

Comment: you mean logged into the machine this program is executed from, or logged into the machine that you are remotely accessing the task schedule for?

Comment: Into the machine that Im accesing to schedule the task. Im trying to change the settings for it but I cant found which one is that.
Im looking for it here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383480(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ideally you'll want to be using some type of service account and you'll use that acct in both your code and if you rdp into the machine for some related reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is working, I just have to add the server paramters on "Connect()"

```
Const TriggerTypeTime = 1
Const ActionTypeExec = 0

Dim service = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
Call service.Connect()

Dim rootFolder
rootFolder = service.GetFolder("\")

Dim taskDefinition
taskDefinition = service.NewTask(0)

Dim regInfo
regInfo = taskDefinition.RegistrationInfo
regInfo.Description = "Testing"
regInfo.Author = "Me"

Dim principal
principal = taskDefinition.Principal

' revisar
principal.LogonType = 3

Dim settings
settings = taskDefinition.Settings
settings.Enabled = True
settings.StartWhenAvailable = True
settings.Hidden = False

Dim triggers
triggers = taskDefinition.Triggers

Dim trigger
trigger = triggers.Create(TriggerTypeTime)

Dim startTime
startTime = L_TraducirParaTrigger(Fecha)

trigger.StartBoundary = startTime
trigger.Id = "TimeTriggerId"
trigger.Enabled = True

Dim Action
Action = taskDefinition.Actions.Create(ActionTypeExec)
Action.Path = "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
Dim url As String = "http://localhost:5000/" & L_IdEjecucion
Action.Arguments = "/c start " & url
'revisar último parámetro
 Call rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(L_Id, taskDefinition, 6, , , 3)
```